# Autofac register generic with multiple paramters?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

Here are the classes and interfaces I'm dealing with.

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    //omitted for brevity...
}
public abstract class UserClientBase<T> : ClientBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected UserClientBase(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress, string userName, string password)
        : base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
        if (ClientCredentials == null) return;

        ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
    }
}
public class AccountProxy : UserClientBase<IAccountService>, IAccountService
{
    private static readonly WSHttpBinding Binding = WcfHelpers.ConfigureWsHttpBinding();
    private static readonly EndpointAddress EndpointAddress =
        new EndpointAddress(@"https://server.project.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc");

    public AccountProxy(string userName, string password)
        : base(Binding, EndpointAddress, userName, password)
    {
    }

    //omitted for brevity
}
public interface ISafeClient<out TService> : IDisposable where TService : class
{
    //omitted for brevity...
}
public class SafeClient<TClient, TService> : ISafeClient<TService>
    where TClient : UserClientBase<TService>, TService
    where TService : class
{
    //omitted for brevity...
}

public AccountController(ISafeClient<IAccountService> accountProxy)
{
    _accountProxy = accountProxy;
}
```

I'm using Asp.net MVC 5 with Autofac integration, here are the registrations in my Global.asax Application_Start method.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterType<AccountProxy>().As<IAccountService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SafeClient<,>)).As(typeof(ISafeClient<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Now when I try to browse to a page handled by the AccountController, I get the following exception in the URL.

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'MyMvcApp.Controllers.AccountController' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Project.Client.Proxies.ISafeClient`1[Project.Client.Contracts.Service.IAccountService]
>   accountProxy' of constructor 'Void

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. When I look in the container's ComponentRegistry at runtime I see the Controllers and the AccountProxy. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I can inject an IAccountService successfully if I register it like this instead:

```
builder.Register(a => new AccountProxy("userName", "password")).As<IAccountService>();
```

However when I try to inject the ISafeClient I still get an exception. I think I have a larger problem here. Essentially, I'm trying to wrap a ClientBase to include safe disposing and retry logic. It handles communication and message exceptions, faulted channel states, etc. Every time I execute a method on my SafeClient, the ClientBase is re-instantiated, then automatically disposed of. If this is the case, should I even be injecting it? Ugghh.. I'm confused.

**Update 2:**
Looks like I can just register like this.

```
builder.RegisterType<SafeClient<AccountProxy, IAccountService>>().As<ISafeClient<IAccountService>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Then my AccountController changes to this:

```
private readonly ISafeClient<IAccountService> _accountProxy;

public AccountController(ISafeClient<IAccountService> accountProxy)
{
    _accountProxy = accountProxy;
}
```

Is there any downside to doing it this way, other than the obvious which is having to register teach safe client individually?

Comment: Could you share your `AccountController` constructor ?

Comment: I've narrowed it down at least. I can't even inject a simple IAccountService into the controller. When doing that I get this error: "Cannot resolve parameter 'System.String userName' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.String, System.String)'." I'm not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: Where do you expect the container to pull the username and password from?

Comment: I can provide the username/password, but think I have a larger issue. Please see my update.

Comment: To resolve `ISafeClient<T>` *Autofac* has to find a `TClient` using the generic type constraint where `TClient : UserClientBase<TService>, TService`. It doesn't seem to be supported out of the box. You can add support for your case using a `RegistrationSource` ... By the way, in your case, it may be easier to works with [WCF extensibility point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx) and /or [interception proxy](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html)